# Copy selected data from one sheet to another sheet in the same workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, vlookup

I need to transfer data from sheet 2 to sheet 1 using either `vlookup` or index/match and VBA.

The data will look like this in sheet 2:

```
SK412   1,986.97    74:10:03

SJ315   2,313.92    53:03:14

SL125   1,573.23    59:30:18

SL134   1,664.52    66:45:10
```

and for sheet 1:

```
SL125   

SK412

SJ315   

SL134
```

Basically the order is jumbled up but I need to copy the respective data in.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just sort in the filter low to high?

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't use excel vlookup formula? What was the problem? Just use VLOOKUP like this for second column:

```
=LOOKUP(A1, 'sheet 2'!$A$1:$C$4,2,FALSE)
```

And for third column:

```
=LOOKUP(A1, 'sheet 2'!$A$1:$C$4,3,FALSE)
```